What equipment is needed to replace multiple AC adapters with a unit that plugs into a single plug?
I'd like to replace 3 different AC adapters with a single wall unit like this one that plugs into a single outlet and has 3 USB-C ports.

From that, I'd run:

USB-C to 12V barrel jack cable to a TP-link AX1800 router whose current AC adapter is specced at 12v, 1.5A DC
USB-C to 12V barrel jack cable to an Arris Surfboard modem whose current AC adapter is specced at 12v, 2.5A DC (using it in bridge mode since its router capability is no longer working reliably, hence the need for the separate router)
Standard USB-C to USB-C cable to Orange Pi Zero 3 microcomputer whose standard power supply is rated at 5V, 3A, but apparently can be run at 2A when running headless

Will the linked products be able to produce enough power - particularly for the 12V 2.5A? I'm confused on the wall unit since it shows 25W / 67W max, and I'm not sure what the difference is between the numerator and denominator there.

flagging as duplicate of https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18962/27496

The charger is rated at 67W maximum.  If only one device is plugged in, you can get up to 67W.  If 3 devices are plugged in, you can only get 25, 20, 20.  This is standard for most chargers.
In theory this may well work.  However, in practice (from my experience), the Pi is very finicky.  Even though it uses an USB connector for power, it requires better specs than the USB can deliver.
You can try the charger.  At least 2 devices will work on it.  If the Pi works intermittently, then you may have to go back to its own adapter.

I use this ISDT Power Station to charge a phone, laptop, and RPi simultaneously. I do find that if I connect extra drain on the RPi 4B (running an attached touch screen off the 5V pin) that I get a low voltage warning on the RPi when using any standard USB-PD charger. The charger that came with the RPi is fixed at 5V, and I don't get the same warning when the display is attached. Normal USB-PD would go up to 5V 3A and then switch to 9V if more power were required, but the RPi will not negotiate to go above 5V. Still any normal 15W USB charger will be more than enough for an RPi with few attachments.
There are plenty of chargers with multiple high power outputs.
This one has several 65W ports and this one has 2x 100W ports.
You do have to be careful to check the ratings. I used to be that almost all chargers would only claim the total power output but when you connect a device to the second port, it lowers the max power of the first port (1x 65W or 2x 25W, but not not capable of 2x65W). Thankfully this is becoming less common and you can find plenty of charging hubs where each port has a dedicated supply. You will have to read the fine print to make sure.
