What equipment is needed to replace multiple AC adapters with a unit that plugs into a single plug?
I'd like to replace 3 different AC adapters with a single wall unit like this one that plugs into a single outlet and has 3 USB-C ports.

From that, I'd run:

USB-C to 12V barrel jack cable to a TP-link AX1800 router whose current AC adapter is specced at 12v, 1.5A DC
USB-C to 12V barrel jack cable to an Arris Surfboard G36 modem whose current AC adapter is specced at 12v, 2.5A DC (using it in bridge mode since its router capability is no longer working reliably, hence the need for the separate router)
Standard USB-C to USB-C cable to Orange Pi Zero 3 microcomputer whose standard power supply is rated at 5V, 3A, but apparently can be run at 2A when running headless

Will the linked products be able to produce enough power - particularly for the 12V 2.5A? I'm confused on the wall unit since it shows 25W / 67W max, and I'm not sure what the difference is between the numerator and denominator there.


I'm confused on the wall unit since it shows 25W / 67W max, and I'm not sure what the difference is between the numerator and denominator there.

Multiple ports vs single port. The unit can supply 67W in total, so if a single port is connected it'll receive the full 67W (assuming the connected device supports USB Power Delivery), but if multiple ports are connected they'll be capped to the indicated 25W+20W+20W.

Will the linked products be able to produce enough power - particularly for the 12V 2.5A?

It's unlikely that your modem needs the full 2.5A on the DC side – that's around 30W at this voltage, and while you didn't specify the model, multiple sources (1, 2) say that most Arris modems need 10-20W (up to ~1.6A at 12V). Its bundled power brick will of course be rated for a bit more than is actually needed.
Likewise, the spec sheet for AX1800 says it draws up to 1A at 12V.
As for total capacity, you already have the numbers:



Device
Power
Worst case




AX1800
12V × 1A = 12W
12V × 1.5A = 18W


Surfboard
12V × ???A = ???W (look at the sticker or spec sheet)
12V × 2.5A = 30W


Pi
5V × 2A = 10W
5V × 3A = 15W



So I'm not sure about your modem (I'd try to measure it, either on the AC side with a "Kill-a-watt" kind of meter, or DC side somehow), but the rest are comfortably below the 20W limit of the USB-C ports you have – enough to account for the possibly-inaccurate calculations I've done.

Does that unit actually support multiple PD voltages when running with multiple ports, or only 5v. I note the max per port when shared is 25w which is suspiciously equal to the 5v maximum power profile.

Since the 12v barrel adapters are only usable If the charger is willing to negotiate 12v output.

I use this ISDT Power Station to charge a phone, laptop, and Raspberry Pi simultaneously. I do find that if I connect extra drain on the Raspberry Pi 4B (running an attached touch screen off the 5V pin) that I get a low voltage warning on the Raspberry Pi when using any standard USB-PD charger.
The charger that came with the Raspberry Pi is fixed at 5V, and I don't get the same warning when the display is attached. Normal USB-PD would go up to 5V 3A and then switch to 9V if more power were required, but the Raspberry Pi will not negotiate to go above 5V. Still any normal 15W USB charger will be more than enough for an Raspberry Pi with few attachments.
There are plenty of chargers with multiple high power outputs.
This one has several 65W ports and this one has 2x 100W ports.
You do have to be careful to check the ratings. It used to be that almost all chargers would only claim the total power output but when you connect a device to the second port, it lowers the max power of the first port (1x 65W or 2x 25W, but not not capable of 2x 65W).
Thankfully this is becoming less common and you can find plenty of charging hubs where each port has a dedicated supply. You will have to read the fine print to make sure.
